# ProxyHTMLURLMap for links within JSON objects

Tags: json, apache, proxy

I'm trying to write a proxy server so I can load a website in an iframe. The site has the "X-FRAME-OPTIONS" set to deny, so I'm purely trying to remove that restriction, which the company that owns the website I am trying to load suggested to me.

I have the proxy working, but some of the content is loaded in via AJAX and JSON objects. My questions is:

Is is possible to rewrite links returned from an AJAX call using ProxyHTMLURLMap? I have already rewritten links that are already in the page, but am having no success with rewriting the links returned in the AJAX response.

Any help much appreciated! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Use mod filter and substitute instead

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ProxyPreserveHost On
        ServerName proxy-test.example.com
        FilterDeclare MYFILTER
        FilterProvider MYFILTER SUBSTITUTE resp=Content-Type $text/
        FilterProvider MYFILTER SUBSTITUTE resp=Content-Type $/xml
        FilterProvider MYFILTER SUBSTITUTE resp=Content-Type $/json
        FilterProvider MYFILTER SUBSTITUTE resp=Content-Type $/javascript
        <Location />
                #disable gzip
                RequestHeader unset Accept-Encoding
                FilterChain MYFILTER
                Substitute "s!(images|static|test).example.com!proxy-$1.example.com!i"
        </Location>
        ProxyPass / http://test.example.com/
        ProxyPassReverse / http://test.example.com/
</VirtualHost>
```